# How should I instantiate a class with a constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I use the database context to inject the constructor, the declaration class needs to take parameters, I want to call the method of the class on the page, and I don't know what parameters should I provide.

```
//Controller
public class Public
{
    private MVCMovieContext _context;

    public Public(MVCMovieContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check your Startup.cs class and ensure that MVCMovieContext is registered with DI injection

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood The database context is work ,my problem is:I have Razor page how can I use the function in the class ,Class cannot be instantiated normally,Thanks

Comment: @Sparkli: If you are using MVC, you need to understand the routing and how the M(model), V(view) and C(controller) works together. When the request comes in, the routing table will match it to a controller. You have your logic inside the controller method called action (the function you're talking about) to fetch whatever data the view needs, and returns it to the View. It sounds like you're unfamiliar with MVC at all. This is a doc to get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood: thanks ,i think i should use ajax for function

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know What parameters should I provide

You don't provide any parameters, that's the whole point of dependency injection, otherwise it would just be regular parameter passing. The framework will create/share the proper database context when it creates your controller as part of handling a request.

Comment: But when the class is instantiated, it asks me to provide the actual parameter corresponding to the "context" of the "public Public(MVCMovieContext context)" in the figure, otherwise the method inside the class cannot be called

Comment: In other words, how do I call the methods of the class from outside after injection?

Comment: @Sparkli: I guess you still don't get it. You don't new up `MVCMovieContext` and pass it in your `Public` class (what a bad name for a class). With the help of the DI, it will automatically inject that for you. That's the whole point of DI.

Comment: Precisely, you never instantiate controllers yourself.

Comment: @David Liang:  I agree for it's bad name,but could you please show me the code that I can use the function, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Maybe my problem is too basic

Comment: You don't use it, the framework uses it for you. Maybe post another question explaining the reason why you're so adamant in using controller classes yourself, because your problem stems from that.

Comment: @Blindy: if i submit form with asp-action ,it will Redirect to new page ,can i just submit form with no Redirect?(except ajax submit)

Comment: Redirect is 301, there is no redirect on submit, there's only a send request of the type you specify (get, post, etc). And you can do your own send requests as you wish, it's just html. If you don't like ajax, use whatever else you like.

Comment: Is there any another way that i can submit?

Comment: Sure, you can use raw sockets if you prefer. Honestly I don't understand your stubbornness to just use standard and tested patterns, but to each his own. Spawn `curl` processes if you find that better!